# Html form value didn't show in PHP

Tags: php, html

Please, the value entered by the user in the input dosen't show in PHP. This is the code

```
<html>

<head></head>
<form method="post" action="hiUser.php">
    Please type your name
    <input type="text" name="u" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the php code

```
<html>

<body>
    <h3> hi user, </h3>
    <?
            echo $_ POST['u']
             Print $u
             ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you have [`short_open_tag`](https://secure.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled? Also `$_ POST['u']` (note the space) might be a typo here, if not, it's invalid. Then there's a `;` missing after `['u']`. You really need to fix the syntax issues first before judging whether your script works.

Comment: Would've been nice to know what *does* show "in PHP".

Comment: It shows only Hi user,

Answer (score 1):

> Form.php

```
<html>

<head></head>
<form method="post" action="hiUser.php">
    Please type your name
    <input type="text" name="u" value="">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

> hiUser.php

```
<html>

<body>
    <h3> hi user, </h3>
    <?php
        echo $u = $_POST['u'] ;
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have not enabled `short_open_tags`

```
<? echo $_ POST['u']
     Print $u
  ?>
```

must be like this

```
<?php $u = $_POST['u'];
     echo $u;
  ?>
```

Comment: I have tried your correction but it still doesn't  show the value imputed by the user.  It only shows Hi user,